# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')

Tags: typescript, react-redux, preact, vite

I'm trying to build a simple Todo App using **Preact + Vite + Typescript + Redux**. But I am facing some compatibility issues with redux and typescript.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')
    at m (react-redux.064eb876.js:3)
    at d (react-redux.064eb876.js:3)
    at d.Provider [as constructor] (react-redux.064eb876.js:1165)
    at d.L [as render] (index.js:506)
    at $ (index.js:178)
    at m (children.js:147)
    at $ (index.js:195)
    at m (children.js:147)
    at $ (index.js:195)
    at M (render.js:36)
```

I have aliased *react & react-dom* in vite.config.ts to *preact-compat*.

```
export default defineConfig(
  {
  esbuild: {
    jsxFactory: 'h',
    jsxFragment: 'Fragment',
  },
  alias:
    [
       {find: 'react', replacement: 'preact/compat'},
       {find: 'react-dom', replacement: 'preact/compat'},
    ],
  plugins: [
    preactRefresh()
  ],
});
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "react": ["node_modules/preact/compat"],
      "react-dom": ["node_modules/preact/compat"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "service-worker.js"]
}
```

main.tsx

```
serviceWorker.register();
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.body!
);
```

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "preact": "^10.5.10",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prefresh/vite": "^2.0.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "vite": "^2.0.0-beta.31"
  },
 ...
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using Preact's Vite preset (https://github.com/preactjs/preset-vite)? Probably just set up your Vite config incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did just that but now my build is not happening. When I run `npm run dev` this happens - `[rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables] Identifier 'h' has already been declared (1:54)
file: /Users/vivek/Projects/TasksApp/TodoApp/src/main.tsx:1:54
error during build:
SyntaxError: Identifier 'h' has already been declared (1:54)`

Comment: Yes, the Vite preset automatically does JSX injection by adding `import { h } from 'preact'` into your files. Don't write them yourself.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info. I must check it out then.

Comment: @rschristian I added preact-vite-preset but now I'm getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/preact_devtools.js?v=35418fc9' does not provide an export named 'addHookName'`.

Answer (score 10):

I got a similar error scratched my head for hours and later on realized that I was using `useEffect` inside my component and had some missing imports then **eslint** asked me to automatically import missing modules & I did that and didn't check where it imported **modules** from as there was no **error** in the editor but in the build process, later on, realized that eslint imported `useEffect` shown below.

`import { useEffect } from "preact/compat"`